Ставится ли запятая в следующем предложении?"
Сейчас мне лучше: я прочел последнюю главу и мысли мои прояснились.
Я полагаю, запятая ставится, ибо можно подставить союз "чтобы".

То есть потому что

Не ставится.
У СПП две основы: я прочёл и мысли прояснились. Но есть общее: мне лучше, относящееся к обеим основам.
Это общее и отменяет запятую.

Запятая не ставится,


если части сложносочиненного предложения имеют общее вводное слово,
общий обособленный член или общую, поясняемую ими, часть сложного
предложения:  Словом, время уже истекло и пора было уходить;  Вопреки
предсказаниям синоптиков, небо уже прояснилось и дождь перестал;  Было
у Анны необъяснимое ощущение: еще чуть-чуть и вся эта история кончится
(Щерб.);  Останавливаться было нельзя: ноги засасывало и следы
наливались водой (Пауст.).


